# How do I know that I have missed notifications on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, notification

When getting notifications while not on the computer, they show up and removed after a few seconds, but I didn't see them.

They are then left in the [notification list](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-notifications.html.en) (<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or click the clock).

The issue is that the top clock **doesn't** show any indication that there are missing notification.

Any idea how to show an indication that there pending/missed notifications?

See screenshots:

**Closed - no indication:**
[image: Closed - no indication]

**Open - notifications exist:**
[image: Open - notifications exist]

Comment: So there's a way and it looks good (see answer- exactly what I wanted). I also use a mac (obligated :(), and couldn't find a way to do it on a mac. Crazy how ubuntu behaves much better then a mac on so many levels!!!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/440382/34468

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the **[Notifications Alert](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/258/notifications-alert-on-user-menu/)** GNOME shell extension. This is how the extension works:

> Whenever there is an unread notification (e.g. chat messages), blinks the message in the user's menu with a color chosen by the user.
> [image: Notifications Alert GNOME shell extension]

The extension also lets you customise the rate of blinking, set up blacklist/whitelist etc.

Another less *flashy* alternative is provided by the [**Always Indicator**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2594/always-indicator/)  extension. This is how this one works:

> Always show the new messages indicator on new messages.
> [image: Always Indicator GNOME shell extension]
>
> Features:
>
> 1. New message indicator is always shown if there are notifications.
> 2. The color of the indicator can be customized.
> 3. If 'do not disturb' is active, the icon is displayed in the custom color if there are notifications.

---

Refer to this to learn more about installing and configuring GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

Comment: That said, the default Gnome system seems buggy. I get a white marker next to the date for a drive that I unmounted 24 hours ago, but for other notifications, no indicator appears.

Comment: Nice, but for some reason it blinks and cannot be configured :(

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Try running `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` in Terminal and configuring from the window it opens. Also you should re-login or reboot or restart GNOME shell after installing the extension.

Comment: The config button appeared. Yay. I changed Blink rate to `0` and now it only paints the notification, without blinking, which is exactly what I wanted!!!
Thanks.